# What's the principle of 'replaceAll' method?

Tags: java, regex

```
String s="a";
System.out.println(s.replaceAll(".*","1"));
```

Why the output of the code above is "11", not "1"?

Comment: Because of `*` which matches a chaarcter zero or more times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of `*` which matches a charcter zero or more times. Use `+` instead you should see   the difference .

Answer (score 2):

Because `.*` matches [Zero length matches](http://www.regular-expressions.info/zerolength.html)

Change to `.+` and you're good.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is happening is that when you dont mention any position of a. It checks before and after for zero occurrences. Hence two 1's get replaced. But if you provide a position for a. Say the first case then there is only one time that there is zero occurrence before a hence only one time the 1 gets printed

```
        String s="a";
        System.out.println(s.replaceAll(".*a","1")); // prints 1
        System.out.println(s.replaceAll(".*","1"));  //prints 11
        System.out.println(s.replaceAll("a.*","1"));  //prints 1
```

The * is for zero or more occurences of preceding text and . is for a wildcard character.